# trouble with numba and the pow function

Tags: python, numba

I've run into trouble with numba when trying to run my own code (moving beyond the tutorial examples). It seems the power function is not handled correctly by the compiler, and I get garbage (all ones). The true results are the p-series sums, and should give:

```
2 1.64493306685
3 1.20205690315
4 1.08232323371
```

If instead of the power function I use something silly like a division, I get expected results, so it is a problem with the specific pow function. Tried using numpy's power function instead, same odd behaviour.

```
from numba import autojit
from numpy import power as npow
N=1000000

def psum(p):
    pval = 0.0
    for ix in xrange(1,N):
        pval+=pow(ix,-p)
    return pval

nsum = autojit()(psum)

for p in range(2,5):
    print p, nsum(p)
```

Before you yell at my code for not being pythonic enough, I know the psum can be written as a one-liner:
    return sum([pow(ix,-p) for ix in xrange(1,N)])

but someone else had already pointed out that numba does not handle functions with list comprehensions.

Comment: I like that you view it as "yelling at your code" and not "yelling at you". First time I've seen that distinction.

Comment: Yes, I don't take coding _that_ personally.

Comment: Problem is "fixed" if I use the math.pow function, but I would still claim numba is mishandling the standard pow function.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be related to numba at all ... numpy.power is enough to demonstrate the problem.  `numpy.power(2, -10)` for some reason gives `0`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `numpy.power` is behaving differently depending on the *type* of the input.  Differently typed arguments are coerced to the same type (e.g. `int` -> `float` if one is an `int` and the other is a `float`).  You're putting in integers, so you're getting integer exponentiation (whatever that means).  Put in a float and all is right with the world.

```
>>> numpy.power(2, -10)
0
>>> numpy.power(2., -10)
0.0009765625
>>> numpy.power(2, -10.)
0.0009765625
```

---

In other words, you want:

```
pval += pow(float(ix), -p)
```

Or, perhaps more efficient would be to pass `p` in as a float:

```
print p, nsum(float(p))
```

Comment: OK, good one, so the code works *and* is significantly optimized by numba if I use (a) `numpy.power(float(ix),-p)` or (b) `math.pow(ix,-p)`. But my main question remains: why does numba not handle python's pow?

Comment: @SergioLucero -- This has __nothing__ to do with `numba`.  As I stated in a comment on your original question, this is all about how _numpy_'s `power` function operates.  python's `math.pow` always coerces the inputs to floats -- Apparently numpy.power doesn't.  I'm not sure why it behaves as it does with integers, but I suppose that `numpy`'s dev forums would probably be a better place for a question like that.

Answer (score 1):

In Python there [are a few rules on type coercion](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/coercion-rules.html) which are helpful to know when doing any math work. I believe you have come across one of them using the builtin `pow` function thanks to different coercion rules using `numba`. (yikes!)

You should update your code to give a `float` value when you need to do any mathematics where accuracy is important.

Here is the code updated with output:

```
from numba import autojit
N = 1000000


def psum(p):
    pval = 0.0
    for ix in xrange(1, N):
        pval += pow(float(ix), float(-p))
    return pval

nsum = autojit()(psum)

for p in range(2, 5):
    print p, nsum(p), psum(p)
```

Output of `python tests.py`:

```
2 1.64493306685 1.64493306685
3 1.20205690315 1.20205690315
4 1.08232323371 1.08232323371
```